# Consistent view of data in SPARK Data Frame

Tags: apache-spark

Considering lazy evaluation, actions, etc. my understanding is from others, that:

- if I make repeated access to a dataframe,

  - that was built from, say, a Hive table,

    - that (the Hive table) is subject to mutation,

      - then this changed data will show up on every dataframe operation that is issued subsequently.

How can I get a consistent dataframe then a la ORACLE's read consistency model, other than copying to a separate non-mutable Hive table?

I am assuming that a TempView will solve the problem, or is that not so? Actually I think not. Performance issues.

Ideally I would like the dataframe will all records persisted, but may be that is not how it works with the lazy protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a consistent dataframe then a la ORACLE's read consistency model, other than copying to a separate non-mutable Hive table?

There is simply no such option.

Naively one could suggest `cache` and forced evaluation:

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
df.cache    // Default StorageLevel - MEMORY_AND_DISK
df.foreach(_ => ())
```

but it just doesn't provide required guarantees, especially in case of node failures. You could increase reliability by setting `StorageLevel` to `MEMORY_AND_DISK_2`, but it still can result in silent correctness errors.

So to be blunt - Spark is not a database, don't try to treat it like a one. if you already use Hive, and mutable state, then skip Spark and use Hive's ACID and transaction options.

Comment: @user9902261 As I thought. So, to give you context: we are developing some KPIs that do not really fit into the SPARK model as such, but our stuff is in KUDU so as to reduce costs - moving away from SAP Hana. I do think my copy will work and that then I am covered, but using a TempView worries me as I found this quote on SO 44011846  ... "Unlike a traditional temp table, a temp view is NOT materialized at all even to memory. It's useful for accessing data in SQL but understand that its statements have to be evaluated EVERY time it's accessed..."